# Possible to install mcrypt in PHP 7.1 on Oracle Linux 7?

Tags: php, mcrypt

Is it possible to install mcrypt in PHP 7.1 running on Oracle Linux 7? This is not listed in the repo [here](http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer_php71/x86_64/index.html).

I thought that I might be able to install it using "yum install epel-release" and "yum -y install php-mcrypt", however the package is listed as unavailable:

yum -y install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package php-mcrypt available.

Comment: No, `mcrypt` is deprecated.  Just like the `mysql_` functions

Comment: ...and will be ***removed*** in version 7.2 of PHP. What did you intend on using mcrypt for?

Comment: It is required to install an application I need. The installer will not run without mcrypt installed.

Comment: Try to downgrade your PHP to 5.6.x

Comment: I have the same problem, but I require 7.1 AND mcrypt.